# Strong parameters with JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I thought that Rails automatically identifies/parses JSON params if the request is recognized as JSON. But the request below:

```
Processing by Api::V1::LinksController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"link"=>"{\"title\":\"My first title\"}"}
```

And the following params method:

```
def link_params
  params.require(:link).permit(:title)
end
```

Results in this error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "{\"title\":\"My first title\"}":String):

Any ideas what the convention here is to get strong params + json working would be much appreciated.

**Update**

Here's the code that makes the request (with the http client [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)):

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api/v1/links.json',
  responseType: 'json',
  params: {
    link: {
      title: "My first title"
    }
  },
})
.then( (response) => {
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem a json body but string. Try to execute request using `postman`, selct `POST` and `raw body` of type `application/json`. It should work.

Comment: Please show the code which make a request to the Rails back-end.

Comment: Did u try parsing JSON? JSON.parse(params) This will give a proper json format, rather than the string

Comment: Updated with the code making the request.

Comment: as per the docs, replace `params:` with `data:`. Does it makes difference?

Comment: @Md. Farhan Memon Thanks a bunch! That resolved it.

Comment: @FellowStranger posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axios-api)

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

Replace `params:` with `data:`.